# How should be the expected json data format to create the dynamic sub-header using jQuery Datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to create the table `heading and sub-heading` dynamically so I need the expected json format data and way to make that kind of table using Jquery datatable. I am giving the screen shot below.

[image]

In this table all data should append dynamically. Here under each header there are two `sub-header(i.e- org and round)` and under these sub-header there are multiple data. I need to make this kind o table using jQuery Datatable for that I need the expected JSON data format and how to make it.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried so far and where exactly is the problem; StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com : I was following the code format from this `https://blog.pheonixsolutions.com/dynamic-column-header-result-ajax-call-jquery-datatable/` link but it could not overcome my requirement.

Comment: The link you have mentioned and [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html) is exactly the answer to your question.

Comment: I have tried this link in my case I am using ajax call to get the data dynamically but it wont help much.

Comment: This is either too broad or unclear or lacking an [mcve].